# C extensions using OpenMP on the Visual Studio compiler called using Cython (or ctypes) gradually slow down to a halt

Tags: c, python-3.x, visual-studio, openmp, cython

I've got a C function that performs some I/O operations and decoding that'd I'd like to call from a python script.

The C function works fine when compiled by the Visual Studio Command Line C compiler, and also works fine when called through Cython with Multithreading disabled. But when called with OpenMP multithreading, works great through the first few million loops, but then the CPU usage slowly decreases for the next few million loops, until it finally grinds to a halt and doesn't fail, but doesn't continue computations either.

The C file is as follows:

```
//block_reader.c

#include "block_reader.h" //contains block_data_t, decode_block, get_block_data
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define NTHREADS 8

int decode_blocks(block_data_t *block_data_array, int num_blocks, int *values){
  int block;
#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(NTHREADS)
  for(block=0; block<num_blocks; block++){
    decode_block(block_data_array[i], values);
  }

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  int num_blocks = 250000, block_size = 4096;
  block_data_t *block_data_array = get_block_data();

  int *values = (long long *)malloc(num_blocks * block_size * sizeof(int));

  int i, block;
  for(i=0; i<1000; i++){
    printf("experiment #%d\n", i+1);

    decode_blocks(block_data_array, values)
    }
  }
}
```

when compiled with `cl /W3 -openmp block_reader.c block_helper.c zstd.lib` on the visual studio x64 command line, the main function loop gets all the way to experiment #1000, with the CPU usage at 90% the entire time (my machine has 8 logical threads, I have no idea why it's capped at 90% in pure C, I get the same issue when I remove num_threads(NTHREADS) from the openMP pragma, but I'm not really worried about it).

However when I wrap it in Cython and loop it in python:

```
#block_reader_wrapper.pyx

from libc.stdlib cimport malloc
from libc.stdio cimport printf
cimport openmp
cimport block_reader_defns #contains block_data_t

import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np

cimport cython

@cython.boundscheck(False)  # Deactivate bounds checking.
@cython.wraparound(False)   # Deactivate negative indexing.
cpdef tuple read_blocks(block_data_array):

  cdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] values = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int32_t)
  cdef int[::1] values_view = values

  decode_blocks(block_data_array, len(block_data_array), num_blocks, &values_view[0])

  return values

cdef extern from "block_reader.h":
  int decode_blocks(char**, b_metadata*, unsigned int, unsigned long long*, long long*, int*)



#setup.block_reader_wrapper.py

from setuptools import setup, Extension
from Cython.Build import cythonize
import numpy

ext_modules = [
    Extension(
        "block_reader_wrapper",
        ["block_reader_wrapper.pyx", "block_reader.c", "block_helper.c"],
        libraries=["zstd"],
        library_dirs=["{dir}/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/lib"],
        include_dirs=['{dir}/vcpkg/installed/x64-windows/include', numpy.get_include()],
        extra_compile_args=['/openmp', '-O2'], #Have tried -O2, -O3 and no optimization
        extra_link_args=['/openmp'], #always gets LINK : warning LNK4044: unrecognized option '/openmp'; ignored despite the docs asking for it https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/parallelism.html
    )
]

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize(ext_modules,
                            gdb_debug=True,
                            annotate=True,
                            )
)


#experiment.py

from block_reader_wrapper import read_blocks
from block_data_gen import get_block_data

for i in range(1000):
  print("experiment", i+1)
  read_blocks(get_block_data())
```

I get to experiment #10 with CPU usage at 100% (and running a little faster than the 90% capped pure C), but then between experiment #11 - experiment #16 the CPU usage slowly decreases in increments of 1 logical thread worth of resources, until the CPU usage hits the bottom of 1 logical thread, however despite my task manager claiming python is using ~20% of my CPU usage, the process stops outputting data. Memory Usage is always fairly low (~10%).

I figure this must have something to do with Cython's linking of OpenMP, perhaps implicitly limiting the number of payloads that I can pass to its worker threads.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated, I need this to ultimately work on Windows *and* Ubuntu, which is why I choose openMP in the first place.

Edit 1: As per DavidW 's suggestion I replaced:

```
cdef np.ndarray[np.int32_t, ndim=1] values = np.zeros(size, dtype=np.int32_t)
```

with:

```
cdef array.array values, values_temp
values_temp = array.array('q', [])
values = array.clone(values_temp, size, zero=True)
```

Unfortunately this has not fixed the problem.

Edit 2 & 3: After profiling the process when it's "ground to a halt", I see that a significant portion of CPU time is spent waiting. Specifically the functions `free_base` and `malloc_base` from the module ucrtbase.dll

Edit 4: I rewrote the wrapper with ctypes instead of cython, which takes advantage of the same C -> Python API, so maybe it's no surprise that the same problem exists (although it grinds to a halt about twice as fast with ctypes over Cython).

VTune Summary:

```
Elapsed Time:   285419.416s
    CPU Time:   22708.709s
    Effective Time: 9230.924s
    Spin Time:  13477.785s
    Overhead Time:  0s
    Total Thread Count: 10
    Paused Time:    0s


Top Hotspots
    Function    Module  CPU Time
    free_base   ucrtbase.dll    9061.852s
    malloc_base ucrtbase.dll    8308.887s
    NtWaitForSingleObject   ntdll.dll   1283.721s
    func@0x180020020    USER32.dll  820.759s
    func@0x18001c630    tsc_block_reader.cp38-win_amd64.pyd 753.774s
    [Others]    N/A*    2479.716s

Effective CPU Utilization Histogram
    Simultaneously Utilized Logical CPUs    Elapsed Time    Utilization threshold

    0   279744.7901384001   Idle
    1   5446.2851121    Poor
    2   177.8078306 Poor
    3   40.3033061  Poor
    4   10.2292884  Poor
    5   0   Poor
    6   0   Poor
    7   0   Ok
    8   0   Ideal
```

Even though it's saying about 80% of the CPU time is Idle, a loop that should complete in 30 seconds didn't even complete after 2 days, so it's much more than 80% Idle time.

Looks like the majority of the Idle time is spent in `ucrtbase.dll`

Comment: This won't be the cause of your problem but there's a lot of cython directives which are serving absolutely no purpose here. Disabling wraparound is completely pointless here; and disabling boundscheck is almost pointless here; there's no reason to define a type for `times` (and that simplifies compilation because you needn't `cimport numpy`); there's little reason to `cpdef read_blocks` or specify a return type.

Comment: My guess would be the problem is that Numpy is linked to some version of OpenMP, which may not be the same as the one MSVC uses. Can you create a version that doesn't use Numpy at all (e.g. use `array.array` for storage) and see if that works?

Comment: @DavidW Thank you for the tips on the Cython directives. Unfortunately after converting the code to use array.arrays (see edit), the problem still persists.

Comment: Thanks for trying. I'm out of ideas I'm afraid.

Comment: I'd use a tool such as Intel VTune or the Visual Studio profiler to see what happens to the program execution once you end up in the "grinds to a halt" state.

Comment: I'm still a bit suspicious that you're loading some Python module (probably Numpy) that's linked to a different implementation of OpenMP and that causes problems - I've seen this happen before on MacOS + Clang + Intel MKL. Unfortunately I think you'll be lucky to get an answer without an [mre].

Comment: Thank you @DavidW, I will scrub my project of all uses of Numpy (and any other modules that may be the culprit. And if that doesn't work, perhaps I'll minimally recreate the problem and ask again.

Comment: Does your program stuck if you run it without openmp directives?